# Using an Elastic Load Balancer without Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-zone, amazon-route53

We have setup an Elastic Beanstalk environment that spins up EC2 instances and adds a classic load balancer in front of them.

Typically, you would set your DNS to Route53's name servers and then use a Route53 ALIAS record to point the domain to the load balancer.

The issue we are facing is that some of our clients will not migrate from their current DNS provider to AWS Route53.

**Question:** How can I point a domain to a load balancer without using Route53?

We are using names.co.uk for the majority of our sites and we are able to amend the following records:

- A
- NS
- CNAME
- MX
- TXT
- AAAA
- SRV

They also have a 'web forwarding' option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use CNAME record to point your domain to AWS classic loadbalancer.